# How to turn `nans` into `zeros` in objects or handles using indexing

Tags: matlab, object, handle

The variable `trackWorkspace` contains `cell` `structures`. The variable `intensityDIV` is a vector array inside `trackworkspace`. I want to turn any `nans` inside `intensityDIV` into zeros. It is giving me an error saying that:**`Insufficient outputs from right hand side to satisfy comma separated list expansion on left hand side. Missing [] are the most likely cause`**.

```
data = [handles.trackWorkspace.intensityDIV];
if any(isnan(data))
    handles.trackWorkspace(isnan(data)).intensityDIV = 0;
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`handles.trackWorkspace(isnan(data)).intensityDIV` creates a [comma separated list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) and to assign values to it, you need to have as many elements on the right hand side as you do in that comma separated list. You only have a single value (`0`) on the right-hand side which is leading to your error.

One way to accomplish this would be to use [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) to supply a `0` for each element

```
[handles.trackWorkspace(isnan(data)).intensityDiv] = deal(0);
```

This specifies *each* `intensityDiv` field as an output and since we only provide one input to `deal`, it provides this same value to *all* outputs.

Comment: It works! But it doesn't seem to give the error when the variable `trackWorkspace` isn't an object or handle. Why is this the case?

Comment: @Senyokbalgul Why would it never not be an object or handle?

Comment: When I use this form `trackWorkspace(isnan(data)).intensityDIV`, it seems to work fine for some reason. It wouldn't be a handle when it is not in Matlab GUI code.